# Publishing a .NET Core / Angular 4 Project to Netlify

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, netlify

Does anyone have experience publishing a .NET/Angular project to Netlify? I'm using the Angular Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates template. On Netlify, I'm getting a non-zero exit code that's preventing me from publishing. Here is my output:

```
9:44:44 AM: Build ready to start
9:44:44 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
9:44:44 AM: Starting to download cache of 8.9MB
9:44:45 AM: Finished downloading cache in 225.765972ms
9:44:45 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
9:45:00 AM: Running build command: dotnet restore && dotnet build && dotnet run
9:45:02 AM: Downloading and installing node v6.11.4...
9:45:02 AM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.4/node-v6.11.4-linux-x64.tar.xz...
9:45:03 AM: 
9:45:03 AM:   0.0%
9:45:03 AM: 
                                                                           1.1%
9:45:03 AM: 
###                                                                        4.9%
9:45:03 AM: 
##############
9:45:03 AM:  19.8%
9:45:03 AM: 
##############################                                            41.7%
9:45:03 AM: 
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:04 AM: #
9:45:05 AM: #
9:45:05 AM: #
9:45:05 AM: #
9:45:05 AM: #
9:45:05 AM: #
9:45:05 AM: #
9:45:05 AM: #
9:45:05 AM: #
9:45:06 AM: #
9:45:06 AM: #
9:45:06 AM: #
9:45:06 AM: #
9:45:06 AM: #
9:45:06 AM: #
9:45:06 AM: #
9:45:06 AM: #
9:45:06 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:07 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: #
9:45:08 AM: 
9:45:08 AM: 
9:45:08 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 
9:45:09 AM: 7
9:45:10 AM: 9
9:45:10 AM: .
9:45:10 AM: 7
9:45:10 AM: %
9:45:10 AM: 
9:45:10 AM: #
9:45:10 AM: #
9:45:10 AM: #
9:45:10 AM: #
9:45:10 AM: #
9:45:10 AM: #
9:45:10 AM: #
9:45:10 AM: #
9:45:10 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:11 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:12 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:13 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:14 AM: #
9:45:15 AM: #
9:45:15 AM: #
9:45:15 AM: #
9:45:15 AM: #
9:45:15 AM: 
9:45:15 AM: 1
9:45:15 AM: 0
9:45:15 AM: 0
9:45:15 AM: .
9:45:15 AM: 0
9:45:15 AM: %
9:45:15 AM: 
9:45:15 AM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
9:45:15 AM: Checksums matched!
9:45:16 AM: Now using node v6.11.4 (npm v3.10.10)
9:45:16 AM: Using version v6.11.4 of node
9:45:16 AM: Using /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
9:45:16 AM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 3.10.10
9:46:25 AM: BrandonCluffPortfolio@0.0.0 /opt/build/repo
├── @angular/animations@4.2.5 
├── @angular/common@4.2.5 
├── @angular/compiler@4.2.5 
├─┬ @angular/compiler-cli@4.2.5 
│ └── minimist@1.2.0 
├── @angular/core@4.2.5 
├── @angular/forms@4.2.5 
├── @angular/http@4.2.5 
├── @angular/platform-browser@4.2.5 
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.2.5 
├── @angular/platform-server@4.2.5 
├── @angular/router@4.2.5 
├── @angular/tsc-wrapped@4.2.5 
├─┬ @ngtools/webpack@1.5.0 
│ └── loader-utils@1.1.0 
├── @types/chai@4.0.1 
├── @types/jasmine@2.5.53 
├── @types/webpack-env@1.13.0 
├── accepts@1.3.3 
├── acorn@5.1.1 
├─┬ acorn-dynamic-import@2.0.2 
│ └── acorn@4.0.13 
├── after@0.8.2 
├── ajv@5.2.0 
├── ajv-keywords@1.5.1 
├─┬ align-text@0.1.4 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├── alphanum-sort@1.0.2 
├── amdefine@1.0.1 
├── angular-font-awesome@2.3.7 
├── angular2-template-loader@0.6.2 
├── ansi-html@0.0.7 
├── ansi-regex@2.1.1 
├── ansi-styles@2.2.1 
├─┬ anymatch@1.3.0 
│ ├── arr-diff@2.0.0 
│ ├── array-unique@0.2.1 
│ ├── braces@1.8.5 
│ ├── expand-brackets@0.1.5 
│ ├── extglob@0.3.2 
│ ├── is-extglob@1.0.0 
│ ├── kind-of@3.2.2 
│ └── micromatch@2.3.11 
├── argparse@1.0.9 
├── arr-diff@4.0.0 
├── arr-flatten@1.1.0 
├── arr-union@3.1.0 
├── array-slice@0.2.3 
├── array-unique@0.3.2 
├── arraybuffer.slice@0.0.6 
├── arrify@1.0.1 
├── asn1.js@4.9.1 
├── aspnet-prerendering@3.0.1 
├── aspnet-webpack@2.0.1 
├── assert@1.4.1 
├── assertion-error@1.0.2 
├── ast-types@0.9.6 
├── async@2.5.0 
├── async-each@1.0.1 
├── atob@2.0.3 
├── autoprefixer@6.7.7 
├─┬ awesome-typescript-loader@3.2.1 
│ └── loader-utils@1.1.0 
├── babel-code-frame@6.22.0 
├── backo2@1.0.2 
├── balanced-match@0.4.2 
├─┬ base@0.11.1 
│ ├── define-property@0.2.5 
│ ├── is-descriptor@0.1.5 
│ ├── isobject@2.1.0 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├── base64-arraybuffer@0.1.5 
├── base64-js@1.2.1 
├── base64id@1.0.0 
├── better-assert@1.0.2 
├── big.js@3.1.3 
├── binary-extensions@1.8.0 
├── blob@0.0.4 
├── bluebird@3.5.0 
├── bn.js@4.11.7 
├─┬ body-parser@1.17.2 
│ └── iconv-lite@0.4.15 
├── bootstrap@3.3.7 
├─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.8 
│ └── balanced-match@1.0.0 
├── braces@2.2.2 
├── brorand@1.1.0 
├── browserify-aes@1.0.6 
├── browserify-cipher@1.0.0 
├── browserify-des@1.0.0 
├── browserify-rsa@4.0.1 
├── browserify-sign@4.0.4 
├── browserify-zlib@0.1.4 
├── browserslist@1.7.7 
├── buffer@4.9.1 
├── buffer-xor@1.0.3 
├── builtin-modules@1.1.1 
├── builtin-status-codes@3.0.0 
├── bytes@2.4.0 
├── cache-base@0.8.5 
├── callsite@1.0.0 
├── camel-case@3.0.0 
├── camelcase@1.2.1 
├── caniuse-api@1.6.1 
├── caniuse-db@1.0.30000697 
├─┬ center-align@0.1.3 
│ └── lazy-cache@1.0.4 
├── chai@4.0.2 
├── chalk@1.1.3 
├── check-error@1.0.2 
├── chokidar@1.7.0 
├── cipher-base@1.0.3 
├── clap@1.2.0 
├─┬ class-utils@0.3.5 
│ ├── define-property@0.2.5 
│ ├── is-descriptor@0.1.5 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├── clean-css@4.1.5 
├── cliui@2.1.0 
├── clone@1.0.2 
├── co@4.6.0 
├── coa@1.0.3 
├── code-point-at@1.1.0 
├── collection-visit@0.2.3 
├── color@0.11.4 
├── color-convert@1.9.0 
├── color-name@1.1.2 
├── color-string@0.3.0 
├── colormin@1.1.2 
├── colors@1.1.2 
├── combine-lists@1.0.1 
├── commander@2.9.0 
├── component-bind@1.0.0 
├── component-emitter@1.2.1 
├── component-inherit@0.0.3 
├── concat-map@0.0.1 
├── connect@3.6.2 
├── console-browserify@1.1.0 
├── constants-browserify@1.0.0 
├── content-type@1.0.2 
├── cookie@0.3.1 
├── copy-descriptor@0.1.1 
├── core-js@2.4.1 
├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
├── create-ecdh@4.0.0 
├── create-hash@1.1.3 
├── create-hmac@1.1.6 
├── crypto-browserify@3.11.0 
├─┬ css@2.2.1 
│ ├── atob@1.1.3 
│ ├── source-map@0.1.43 
│ ├── source-map-resolve@0.3.1 
│ └── source-map-url@0.3.0 
├── css-color-names@0.0.4 
├─┬ css-loader@0.28.4 
│ └── loader-utils@1.1.0 
├── css-selector-tokenizer@0.7.0 
├── cssesc@0.1.0 
├── cssnano@3.10.0 
├── csso@2.3.2 
├── custom-event@1.0.1 
├── date-now@0.1.4 
├── debug@2.6.7 
├── decamelize@1.2.0 
├─┬ deep-eql@2.0.2 
│ └── type-detect@3.0.0 
├── define-property@1.0.0 
├── defined@1.0.0 
├── depd@1.1.0 
├── des.js@1.0.0 
├── di@0.0.1 
├── diffie-hellman@5.0.2 
├── dom-serialize@2.2.1 
├── domain-browser@1.1.7 
├── domain-context@0.5.1 
├── domain-task@3.0.3 
├── ee-first@1.1.1 
├── electron-to-chromium@1.3.15 
├── elliptic@6.4.0 
├── emojis-list@2.1.0 
├── encodeurl@1.0.1 
├── encoding@0.1.12 
├─┬ engine.io@1.8.3 
│ ├── debug@2.3.3 
│ └── ms@0.7.2 
├─┬ engine.io-client@1.8.3 
│ ├── debug@2.3.3 
│ └── ms@0.7.2 
├── engine.io-parser@1.3.2 
├─┬ enhanced-resolve@3.3.0 
│ └── memory-fs@0.4.1 
├── ent@2.2.0 
├── errno@0.1.4 
├── error-ex@1.3.1 
├── es6-promise@3.3.1 
├── es6-shim@0.35.3 
├── es6-templates@0.2.3 
├── escape-html@1.0.3 
├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 
├── esprima@2.7.3 
├── esutils@2.0.2 
├── event-source-polyfill@0.0.9 
├── eventemitter3@1.2.0 
├── events@1.1.1 
├── evp_bytestokey@1.0.0 
├─┬ expand-braces@0.1.2 
│ ├── array-unique@0.2.1 
│ ├── braces@0.1.5 
│ ├── expand-range@0.1.1 
│ ├── is-number@0.1.1 
│ └── repeat-string@0.2.2 
├─┬ expand-brackets@2.1.4 
│ ├── define-property@0.2.5 
│ ├── is-descriptor@0.1.5 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├─┬ expand-range@1.8.2 
│ ├── fill-range@2.2.3 
│ ├── is-number@2.1.0 
│ ├── isobject@2.1.0 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├── expose-loader@0.7.3 
├── extend@3.0.1 
├── extend-shallow@2.0.1 
├─┬ extglob@1.1.0 
│ ├── define-property@0.2.5 
│ ├── is-descriptor@0.1.5 
│ ├── kind-of@3.2.2 
│ └─┬ to-regex@2.1.0 
│   └── regex-not@0.1.2 
├─┬ extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2 
│ └── loader-utils@1.1.0 
├── fast-deep-equal@0.1.0 
├── fastparse@1.1.1 
├─┬ file-loader@0.11.2 
│ └── loader-utils@1.1.0 
├── filename-regex@2.0.1 
├── fill-range@4.0.0 
├── finalhandler@1.0.3 
├── find-up@1.1.2 
├── flatten@1.0.2 
├── font-awesome@4.7.0 
├── for-in@1.0.2 
├── for-own@0.1.5 
├── fragment-cache@0.2.1 
├── fs-access@1.0.1 
├── fs.realpath@1.0.0 
├── function-bind@1.1.0 
├── get-caller-file@1.0.2 
├── get-func-name@2.0.0 
├── get-value@2.0.6 
├── glob@7.1.2 
├── glob-base@0.3.0 
├── glob-parent@2.0.0 
├── graceful-fs@4.1.11 
├── graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
├── has@1.0.1 
├── has-ansi@2.0.0 
├─┬ has-binary@0.1.7 
│ └── isarray@0.0.1 
├── has-cors@1.1.0 
├── has-flag@1.0.0 
├─┬ has-value@0.3.1 
│ └── isobject@2.1.0 
├── has-values@0.1.4 
├── hash-base@2.0.2 
├── hash.js@1.1.3 
├── he@1.1.1 
├── hmac-drbg@1.0.1 
├── hosted-git-info@2.5.0 
├── html-comment-regex@1.1.1 
├── html-entities@1.2.1 
├─┬ html-loader@0.4.5 
│ └── loader-utils@1.1.0 
├── html-minifier@3.5.2 
├── http-errors@1.6.1 
├── http-proxy@1.16.2 
├── https-browserify@0.0.1 
├── iconv-lite@0.4.18 
├── icss-replace-symbols@1.1.0 
├─┬ icss-utils@2.1.0 
│ ├── ansi-styles@3.1.0 
│ ├── chalk@2.0.1 
│ ├── has-flag@2.0.0 
│ ├── postcss@6.0.6 
│ └── supports-color@4.1.0 
├── ieee754@1.1.8 
├── indexes-of@1.0.1 
├── indexof@0.0.1 
├── inflight@1.0.6 
├── inherits@2.0.3 
├── interpret@1.0.3 
├── invert-kv@1.0.0 
├── is-absolute-url@2.1.0 
├─┬ is-accessor-descriptor@0.1.6 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├── is-arrayish@0.2.1 
├── is-binary-path@1.0.1 
├── is-buffer@1.1.5 
├── is-builtin-module@1.0.0 
├─┬ is-data-descriptor@0.1.4 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├─┬ is-descriptor@1.0.0 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├── is-dotfile@1.0.3 
├── is-equal-shallow@0.1.3 
├── is-extendable@0.1.1 
├── is-extglob@2.1.1 
├── is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 
├─┬ is-glob@2.0.1 
│ └── is-extglob@1.0.0 
├─┬ is-number@3.0.0 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├── is-odd@1.0.0 
├── is-plain-obj@1.1.0 
├── is-plain-object@2.0.3 
├── is-posix-bracket@0.1.1 
├── is-primitive@2.0.0 
├── is-stream@1.1.0 
├── is-svg@2.1.0 
├── is-utf8@0.2.1 
├── isarray@1.0.0 
├── isbinaryfile@3.0.2 
├── isexe@2.0.0 
├── isobject@3.0.1 
├── isomorphic-fetch@2.2.1 
├── jasmine-core@2.6.4 
├── jquery@3.2.1 
├── js-base64@2.1.9 
├── js-tokens@3.0.2 
├── js-yaml@3.7.0 
├── jsesc@0.5.0 
├── json-loader@0.5.4 
├── json-schema-traverse@0.3.1 
├── json-stable-stringify@1.0.1 
├── json3@3.3.2 
├── json5@0.5.1 
├── jsonify@0.0.0 
├─┬ karma@1.7.0 
│ └── lodash@3.10.1 
├── karma-chai@0.1.0 
├── karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0 
├── karma-cli@1.0.1 
├── karma-jasmine@1.1.0 
├─┬ karma-webpack@2.0.3 
│ ├── async@0.9.2 
│ ├── lodash@3.10.1 
│ └── source-map@0.1.43 
├── kind-of@4.0.0 
├── lazy-cache@2.0.2 
├── lcid@1.0.0 
├── load-json-file@1.1.0 
├── loader-runner@2.3.0 
├── loader-utils@0.2.17 
├── lodash@4.17.4 
├── lodash.camelcase@4.3.0 
├── lodash.memoize@4.1.2 
├── lodash.uniq@4.5.0 
├─┬ log4js@0.6.38 
│ ├── isarray@0.0.1 
│ ├── readable-stream@1.0.34 
│ ├── semver@4.3.6 
│ └── string_decoder@0.10.31 
├── longest@1.0.1 
├── lower-case@1.1.4 
├── lru-cache@2.2.4 
├── macaddress@0.2.8 
├── magic-string@0.19.1 
├── map-cache@0.2.2 
├── map-visit@0.1.5 
├── math-expression-evaluator@1.2.17 
├── media-typer@0.3.0 
├── memory-fs@0.3.0 
├── micromatch@3.0.3 
├── miller-rabin@4.0.0 
├── mime@1.3.6 
├── mime-db@1.27.0 
├── mime-types@2.1.15 
├── minimalistic-assert@1.0.0 
├── minimalistic-crypto-utils@1.0.1 
├── minimatch@3.0.4 
├── minimist@0.0.8 
├── mixin-deep@1.2.0 
├── mkdirp@0.5.1 
├── ms@2.0.0 
├── nanomatch@1.2.0 
├── ncname@1.0.0 
├── negotiator@0.6.1 
├── no-case@2.3.1 
├── node-fetch@1.7.1 
├─┬ node-libs-browser@2.0.0 
│ └── string_decoder@0.10.31 
├── normalize-package-data@2.4.0 
├── normalize-path@2.1.1 
├── normalize-range@0.1.2 
├── normalize-url@1.9.1 
├── null-check@1.0.0 
├── num2fraction@1.2.2 
├── number-is-nan@1.0.1 
├── object-assign@4.1.1 
├── object-component@0.0.3 
├─┬ object-copy@0.1.0 
│ ├── define-property@0.2.5 
│ ├── is-descriptor@0.1.5 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├─┬ object-visit@0.3.4 
│ └── isobject@2.1.0 
├── object.omit@2.0.1 
├─┬ object.pick@1.2.0 
│ └── isobject@2.1.0 
├── on-finished@2.3.0 
├── once@1.4.0 
├── optimist@0.6.1 
├── options@0.0.6 
├── os-browserify@0.2.1 
├── os-locale@1.4.0 
├── os-tmpdir@1.0.2 
├── pako@0.2.9 
├── param-case@2.1.1 
├── parse-asn1@5.1.0 
├─┬ parse-glob@3.0.4 
│ └── is-extglob@1.0.0 
├── parse-json@2.2.0 
├─┬ parse5@3.0.2 
│ └── @types/node@6.0.79 
├── parsejson@0.0.3 
├── parseqs@0.0.5 
├── parseuri@0.0.5 
├── parseurl@1.3.1 
├── pascalcase@0.1.1 
├── path-browserify@0.0.0 
├── path-exists@2.1.0 
├── path-is-absolute@1.0.1 
├── path-parse@1.0.5 
├── path-type@1.1.0 
├── pathval@1.1.0 
├── pbkdf2@3.0.12 
├── pify@2.3.0 
├── pinkie@2.0.4 
├── pinkie-promise@2.0.1 
├── posix-character-classes@0.1.1 
├─┬ postcss@5.2.17 
│ └── supports-color@3.2.3 
├── postcss-calc@5.3.1 
├── postcss-colormin@2.2.2 
├── postcss-convert-values@2.6.1 
├── postcss-discard-comments@2.0.4 
├── postcss-discard-duplicates@2.1.0 
├── postcss-discard-empty@2.1.0 
├── postcss-discard-overridden@0.1.1 
├── postcss-discard-unused@2.2.3 
├── postcss-filter-plugins@2.0.2 
├── postcss-merge-idents@2.1.7 
├── postcss-merge-longhand@2.0.2 
├── postcss-merge-rules@2.1.2 
├── postcss-message-helpers@2.0.0 
├── postcss-minify-font-values@1.0.5 
├── postcss-minify-gradients@1.0.5 
├── postcss-minify-params@1.2.2 
├── postcss-minify-selectors@2.1.1 
├─┬ postcss-modules-extract-imports@1.1.0 
│ ├── ansi-styles@3.1.0 
│ ├── chalk@2.0.1 
│ ├── has-flag@2.0.0 
│ ├── postcss@6.0.6 
│ └── supports-color@4.1.0 
├─┬ postcss-modules-local-by-default@1.2.0 
│ ├── ansi-styles@3.1.0 
│ ├── chalk@2.0.1 
│ ├── has-flag@2.0.0 
│ ├── postcss@6.0.6 
│ └── supports-color@4.1.0 
├─┬ postcss-modules-scope@1.1.0 
│ ├── ansi-styles@3.1.0 
│ ├── chalk@2.0.1 
│ ├── has-flag@2.0.0 
│ ├── postcss@6.0.6 
│ └── supports-color@4.1.0 
├─┬ postcss-modules-values@1.3.0 
│ ├── ansi-styles@3.1.0 
│ ├── chalk@2.0.1 
│ ├── has-flag@2.0.0 
│ ├── postcss@6.0.6 
│ └── supports-color@4.1.0 
├── postcss-normalize-charset@1.1.1 
├── postcss-normalize-url@3.0.8 
├── postcss-ordered-values@2.2.3 
├── postcss-reduce-idents@2.4.0 
├── postcss-reduce-initial@1.0.1 
├── postcss-reduce-transforms@1.0.4 
├── postcss-selector-parser@2.2.3 
├── postcss-svgo@2.1.6 
├── postcss-unique-selectors@2.0.2 
├── postcss-value-parser@3.3.0 
├── postcss-zindex@2.2.0 
├── preboot@4.5.2 
├── prepend-http@1.0.4 
├── preserve@0.2.0 
├── private@0.1.7 
├── process@0.11.10 
├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7 
├── prr@0.0.0 
├── public-encrypt@4.0.0 
├── punycode@1.4.1 
├── q@1.5.0 
├── qjobs@1.1.5 
├── qs@6.4.0 
├── query-string@4.3.4 
├── querystring@0.2.0 
├── querystring-es3@0.2.1 
├── randomatic@1.1.7 
├── randombytes@2.0.5 
├── range-parser@1.2.0 
├─┬ raw-body@2.2.0 
│ └── iconv-lite@0.4.15 
├── raw-loader@0.5.1 
├── read-pkg@1.1.0 
├── read-pkg-up@1.0.1 
├── readable-stream@2.3.3 
├── readdirp@2.1.0 
├─┬ recast@0.11.23 
│ └── esprima@3.1.3 
├── reduce-css-calc@1.3.0 
├── reduce-function-call@1.0.2 
├── reflect-metadata@0.1.10 
├── regenerate@1.3.2 
├── regex-cache@0.4.3 
├── regex-not@1.0.0 
├── regexpu-core@1.0.0 
├── regjsgen@0.2.0 
├── regjsparser@0.1.5 
├── relateurl@0.2.7 
├── remove-trailing-separator@1.0.2 
├── repeat-element@1.1.2 
├── repeat-string@1.6.1 
├── require-directory@2.1.1 
├── require-from-string@1.2.1 
├── require-main-filename@1.0.1 
├── requires-port@1.0.0 
├── resolve@1.3.3 
├── resolve-url@0.2.1 
├── right-align@0.1.3 
├── rimraf@2.6.1 
├── ripemd160@2.0.1 
├── rxjs@5.4.2 
├── safe-buffer@5.1.1 
├── sax@1.2.4 
├── schema-utils@0.3.0 
├── semver@5.3.0 
├── set-blocking@2.0.0 
├── set-getter@0.1.0 
├── set-immediate-shim@1.0.1 
├── set-value@0.4.3 
├── setimmediate@1.0.5 
├── setprototypeof@1.0.3 
├── sha.js@2.4.8 
├─┬ snapdragon@0.8.1 
│ ├── define-property@0.2.5 
│ ├── is-descriptor@0.1.5 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├── snapdragon-node@2.1.1 
├─┬ snapdragon-util@3.0.1 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├─┬ socket.io@1.7.3 
│ ├── debug@2.3.3 
│ ├── ms@0.7.2 
│ └── object-assign@4.1.0 
├─┬ socket.io-adapter@0.5.0 
│ ├── debug@2.3.3 
│ └── ms@0.7.2 
├─┬ socket.io-client@1.7.3 
│ ├── debug@2.3.3 
│ └── ms@0.7.2 
├─┬ socket.io-parser@2.3.1 
│ ├── component-emitter@1.1.2 
│ ├── debug@2.2.0 
│ ├── isarray@0.0.1 
│ └── ms@0.7.1 
├── sort-keys@1.1.2 
├── source-list-map@0.1.8 
├── source-map@0.5.6 
├── source-map-resolve@0.5.0 
├── source-map-support@0.4.15 
├── source-map-url@0.4.0 
├── spdx-correct@1.0.2 
├── spdx-expression-parse@1.0.4 
├── spdx-license-ids@1.2.2 
├── split-string@2.1.1 
├── sprintf-js@1.0.3 
├── startbootstrap-full-slider@4.0.0-alpha 
├─┬ static-extend@0.1.2 
│ ├── define-property@0.2.5 
│ ├── is-descriptor@0.1.5 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├── statuses@1.3.1 
├── stream-browserify@2.0.1 
├── stream-http@2.7.2 
├── strict-uri-encode@1.1.0 
├── string-width@1.0.2 
├── string_decoder@1.0.3 
├── strip-ansi@3.0.1 
├── strip-bom@2.0.0 
├─┬ style-loader@0.18.2 
│ └── loader-utils@1.1.0 
├── supports-color@2.0.0 
├── svgo@0.7.2 
├── symbol-observable@1.0.4 
├── tapable@0.2.6 
├── through@2.3.8 
├── timers-browserify@2.0.2 
├── tmp@0.0.31 
├── to-array@0.1.4 
├── to-arraybuffer@1.0.1 
├─┬ to-object-path@0.3.0 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├─┬ to-regex@3.0.1 
│ ├── define-property@0.2.5 
│ ├── is-descriptor@0.1.5 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├── to-regex-range@2.1.1 
├── to-string-loader@1.1.5 
├─┬ tsickle@0.21.6 
│ └── minimist@1.2.0 
├── tslib@1.7.1 
├── tty-browserify@0.0.0 
├── type-detect@4.0.3 
├── type-is@1.6.15 
├── typescript@2.4.1 
├── uglify-js@3.0.23 
├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 
├── ultron@1.0.2 
├── union-value@0.2.4 
├── uniq@1.0.1 
├── uniqid@4.1.1 
├── uniqs@2.0.0 
├── unpipe@1.0.0 
├── unset-value@0.1.2 
├── upper-case@1.1.3 
├── urix@0.1.0 
├─┬ url@0.11.0 
│ └── punycode@1.3.2 
├─┬ url-loader@0.5.9 
│ └── loader-utils@1.1.0 
├─┬ use@2.0.2 
│ ├── define-property@0.2.5 
│ ├── is-descriptor@0.1.5 
│ └── kind-of@3.2.2 
├── useragent@2.2.0 
├─┬ util@0.10.3 
│ └── inherits@2.0.1 
├── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
├── utils-merge@1.0.0 
├── validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1 
├── vendors@1.0.1 
├── vlq@0.2.2 
├── vm-browserify@0.0.4 
├── void-elements@2.0.1 
├── watchpack@1.3.1 
├─┬ webpack@2.5.1 
│ ├── ajv@4.11.8 
│ ├── memory-fs@0.4.1 
│ ├── source-list-map@1.1.2 
│ ├── supports-color@3.2.3 
│ ├─┬ uglify-js@2.8.29 
│ │ └── yargs@3.10.0 
│ └── webpack-sources@0.2.3 
├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@1.11.0 
│ └── memory-fs@0.4.1 
├── webpack-hot-middleware@2.18.2 
├── webpack-merge@4.1.0 
├── webpack-node-externals@1.6.0 
├─┬ webpack-sources@1.0.1 
│ └── source-list-map@2.0.0 
├── whatwg-fetch@2.0.3 
├── whet.extend@0.9.9 
├── which@1.2.14 
├── which-module@1.0.0 
├── window-size@0.1.0 
├── wordwrap@0.0.2 
├── wrap-ansi@2.1.0 
├── wrappy@1.0.2 
├── ws@1.1.2 
├── wtf-8@1.0.0 
├── xhr2@0.1.4 
├── xml-char-classes@1.0.0 
├── xmlhttprequest-ssl@1.5.3 
├── xtend@4.0.1 
├── y18n@3.2.1 
├─┬ yargs@6.6.0 
│ ├── camelcase@3.0.0 
│ └── cliui@3.2.0 
├─┬ yargs-parser@4.2.1 
│ └── camelcase@3.0.0 
├── yeast@0.1.2 
└── zone.js@0.8.12
9:46:25 AM: npm
9:46:25 AM: WARN
9:46:25 AM: optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
9:46:25 AM: npm
9:46:25 AM: 
9:46:25 AM: WARN
9:46:25 AM: notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
9:46:25 AM: NPM modules installed
9:46:31 AM: npm
9:46:31 AM:  WARN
9:46:31 AM: deprecated bower@1.8.2: ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
9:46:46 AM: BrandonCluffPortfolio@0.0.0 /opt/build/repo
└── bower@1.8.2
9:46:46 AM: npm
9:46:46 AM: 
9:46:46 AM: WARN
9:46:46 AM:  optional
9:46:46 AM:  SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm
9:46:46 AM: 
9:46:46 AM: WARN
9:46:46 AM: notsup
9:46:46 AM:  SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
9:46:47 AM: Installing bower components
9:46:48 AM: bower jquery-validation#1.14.0       not-cached https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation.git#1.14.0
9:46:48 AM: bower jquery-validation#1.14.0          resolve https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation.git#1.14.0
bower bootstrap#3.3.6                not-cached https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.6
bower bootstrap#3.3.6                   resolve https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.6
bower jquery-validation-unobtrusive#3.2.6       not-cached https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive.git#3.2.6
bower jquery-validation-unobtrusive#3.2.6          resolve https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive.git#3.2.6
9:46:48 AM: bower jquery#2.2.0                              not-cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.0
bower jquery#2.2.0                                 resolve https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.0
9:46:49 AM: bower jquery-validation#1.14.0                    download https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/archive/1.14.0.tar.gz
9:46:49 AM: bower bootstrap#3.3.6                             download https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.3.6.tar.gz
9:46:49 AM: bower jquery-validation-unobtrusive#3.2.6         download https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/archive/v3.2.6.tar.gz
9:46:49 AM: bower jquery#2.2.0                                download https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist/archive/2.2.0.tar.gz
9:46:49 AM: bower jquery-validation-unobtrusive#3.2.6          extract archive.tar.gz
9:46:49 AM: bower jquery-validation-unobtrusive#3.2.6         resolved https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive.git#3.2.6
9:46:49 AM: bower bootstrap#3.3.6                              extract archive.tar.gz
9:46:49 AM: bower jquery-validation#1.14.0                     extract archive.tar.gz
9:46:50 AM: bower jquery#2.2.0                                 extract archive.tar.gz
9:46:50 AM: bower jquery#2.2.0                                resolved https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.0
9:46:51 AM: bower jquery-validation#1.14.0                    resolved https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation.git#1.14.0
9:46:51 AM: bower bootstrap#3.3.6                             resolved https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.6
9:46:51 AM: bower jquery-validation-unobtrusive#3.2.6          install jquery-validation-unobtrusive#3.2.6
9:46:51 AM: bower jquery#2.2.0                                 install jquery#2.2.0
9:46:51 AM: bower jquery-validation#1.14.0                     install jquery-validation#1.14.0
9:46:51 AM: bower bootstrap#3.3.6                              install bootstrap#3.3.6
9:46:52 AM: 
jquery-validation-unobtrusive#3.2.6 bower_components/jquery-validation-unobtrusive
├── jquery#2.2.0
└── jquery-validation#1.14.0

jquery#2.2.0 bower_components/jquery

jquery-validation#1.14.0 bower_components/jquery-validation
└── jquery#2.2.0

bootstrap#3.3.6 bower_components/bootstrap
└── jquery#2.2.0
9:46:52 AM: Bower components installed
9:46:52 AM: /opt/build/build.sh: line 427: dotnet: command not found
9:46:52 AM: Cached bower components
9:46:52 AM: Cached NPM modules
9:46:53 AM: Build complete: exit code: 127
9:46:53 AM: Cleaning up docker container
9:46:53 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 127
9:46:54 AM: An error occurred while building the site, skipping the deploy and cache refresh.
9:46:54 AM: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 127
9:46:55 AM: Finished processing build request in 2m11.21141446s
```

I'm not sure what other information would be helpful here. Please let me know, and I will post it.

Comment: By default SPA template for Angular doesn't have reference on bower. So you probably changed something... You have an error at "/opt/build/build.sh: line 427: dotnet: command not found" is it your file? Can you post it out too?

Comment: I think /opt/build/build.sh is on Netlify. I'm guessing that the "Deploy Settings" on Netlify is modifying this build.sh script. I set my build command to be "dotnet restore && dotnet build && dotnet run".

Comment: I had the same problem when dotnet command was run from wrong directory (not where my proj file is) so probably you can try to specify a relative path to your proj file after each command but first you need to output current directory to see where you are.

Comment: Hrm. I'm not sure what you mean. Locally, I run the dotnet commands from the root of my repo. Does Netlify start you somewhere else?

Comment: I think the real issue is that Netlify doesn't know what the dotnet command is. I believe there are ways to get this to work: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/18/how-our-build-bots-build-sites/

Comment: Yeah - it also possible but as I sad dotnet will tell you that dotnet command not found when you run it from the folder where there are no sln or proj files. So just keep it in mind too. Since I don't even know what netlify is:))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disclaimer:  I work for Netlify

As we mentioned to you in your helpdesk ticket on this same topic, our deploy environment is very naked - you have to:

1. specify dependencies that we can automatically install - npm/yarn deps, bower deps, gems and python packages.
2. install other dependencies yourself.  the 'dotnet' program will be one of this type.  We don't have it in our install environment, so you need to somehow import a copy of it into the environment.  Seems like you can download the entire SDK here:  https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux and then you need to import ONLY what is necessary for your build - it will take a very long time to build your site if we have to download the entire SDK, so see what you can trim down to get 'dotnet' to run.

For the purposes of #2, you'll probably need to test things in our build environment.  How to do that, and details you'll need about the build environment such as OS type so you can download the right version of the SDK are described in this article:

https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/18/how-our-build-bots-build-sites/

This will take some work on your part.  It will not be trivial.  It is not something we can help with in more detail than that for free customers unless you come with specific questions and examples.

To address some thoughts in the comments:

- build.sh is indeed our build script
- 9:46:52 AM: /opt/build/build.sh: line 427: dotnet: command not found means that literally there is no dotnet command available to run - not that some config file is missing.
- we only try to run it once since you have set your command to use `&&` to chain several commands - one fails, the whole chain fails, and we don't need to run it two more times once the first failure occurs :)

Comment: I was unable to get this working well. For Angular, I switched to Firebase. I'm marking this answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks for this usefull answer. What about MSSQL coneection. Do we need set up an sql server and connect it externally?

Comment: Yes, you would need to @hijacker83; Netlify provides no database.  Most folks don't connect directly to their database from the client, though, since that means you tell the client the credentials for your database :P . This [function](https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/) may help:  https://github.com/netlify/code-examples/tree/master/function_examples/token-hider