# Netlify and ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, hosting, web-hosting, netlify

any one have idea: How to deploy ASP.NET Core API on https://www.netlify.com ?
I tried this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NOmadyM1Ao , but it not worked for ASP.NET Core API , and I have no idea how to do that , and its documentation https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#sample-file is ambiguous and its difficult to understand , pleas any one have easy way or clear way for deploying ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is possible but not easy. Have a look at this answer.

[Publishing a .NET Core / Angular 4 Project to Netlify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795384/publishing-a-net-core-angular-4-project-to-netlify)

Similar to creating a docker container for your application, you have to specify a set of steps to build your app including downloading the dotnet core SDK.